# Is there any other way to make Android apps besides Eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse

I've installed eclipse but when I start new project it doesn't create the *.xml* file in layout folder nor the java file in the *src* folder, they are empty, so I read I needed to install some plugins and I did but now I can't make virtual device, so I am slowly giving up on this, it's way too complicating and buggy as it seems to me. So is there any other way to create android apps, I already make flash games in *as2* and *as3* but I heard that it's better not to make games for android in flash because they require AIR plugin. So does anyone know how to fix these bugs in eclipse, or any other program for making android apps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, see Android Studio: http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio.html

Keep in mind this is in Alpha, so don't get mad if there's a few bugs. I use it for android programming, and it's pretty stable.

EDIT:

Android Studio uses Gradle, which can be hard to use, and can lead to some errors, as the program is still in alpha. Eclipse runs slower, and uses more RAM in my experience, but it does have more support and user base than IntellJ (which Android Studio is based from). Also, Android Studio shows better previous of .xmls, and they also have some awesome code completion software. I would recommend Android Studio if you're ok with asking a gradle question once and a while.

Comment: thanks dude! But can you please just compare the two for me, tell me the advantages of both if possible?

Comment: I edited my post with the pros and cons. Right now, Android Studio 0.5.1 is pretty stable in my use, and if you're making basic apps, you don't have to deal with Gradle much. I've worked on a few apps in Android Studio, and I only had a problem with it once.

Comment: I don't recommend Android Studio right now, especially not for a beginner. In general it is ok, but there are still many areas where it is lacking. I have used Android Studio a lot and although it is better now you still have to spend a lot of time just fixing bugs and wasting time for no reason. IntelliJ is the goto IDE.

Answer (score 2):

Download the ADT Bundle from this link: http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html

It works out of the box! You can use Android Studio as was suggested in the other answer but it is not a finished product and therefore lacks in many areas.

IntelliJ Idea which is the basis for Android Studio is at the moment pretty much the best IDE for Android and in general Java programming. So I recommend you give IntelliJ a try. The community edition is free and has all the features you need! You can download it here:
http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/

Comment: Is there any program maybe similar to flash, where I can like make objects and assign codes to them, this eclipse is very complex as I can see, it's not very much object oriented as I can see...

Comment: What are you talking about? Eclipse is just the IDE, what does that have to do with object orientation? And the language is Java of course it's object oriented.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use [Xamarin](https://xamarin.com/). It allows you to develop native Android applications using C#. Also Xamarin supports other mobile platforms.

Answer (score 1):

You can also create an android project from the command line, then open that project in eclipse.

this is the example from Android Developer, for more info check this link [managing projects from command line](http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/projects-cmdline.html)

```
android create project \
--target 1 \
--name MyAndroidApp \
--path ./MyAndroidAppProject \
--activity MyAndroidAppActivity \
--package com.example.myandroid
```