# Cannot create a android project in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

[image][image: this is the error in "compiler with" section, nothing showing up and I cant press finish or next to create project]

[image: enter SDK manager is up to date]

[image: Even Eclipse said it is update]

-this is the error in "compiler with" section, nothing showing up and I cant press finish or next to create project.

-SDK manager is up to date

-Even Eclipse said it is update

any suggestion plz ?

Just ignore the Unregistered version at the middle, thanks

Comment: did you restart eclipse?

Comment: yes I do, i restart SDK as well, but nothing showing up

Comment: Do u think is something about the path between Esclipes and SDK Manager is not correct?

Comment: You can check my answer to a similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22277185/2157590)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ADT Plugin version` and `android build tools` **MISMATCHED** thats why u have that `error`

in eclipse Click  on `Help` tab then click on `Check for updates`.

> Update ur ADT Plugin ur problem will be solved.

Answer (score 0):

check Android SDK Reference in Eclipse --> Window --> Preference --> Android . Check also Android SDK path doesn't contain spaces to avoid issues.

Comment: I hv uploaded the current setting, would u mind to hv a look plz

Comment: Can you update your ADT as it mentioned in your first image, you attached